# Issue sending url in json

Tags: php, json, urlencode

I am sending a json response like this:

```
[{"Link":{"iTune":"https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/in\/app\/mx-video-player-play-hd-videos\/id730291646?mt=8"}}]
```

But the problem is associated with this is that this contains the special character

my code:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
    $gamePlatform[] = array("Link" => array('iTune' => $iTune));

        echo json_encode($gamePlatform);
```

how to send the proper link guys please help me out

Comment: You missed an array? echo json_encode(array(array("Link" => array('iTune' => $iTune))));

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/mx-video-player-play-hd-videos/id730291646?mt=8%  This will be the exact url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str_replace()`:

```
    $gamePlatform[] = array("Link" => array('iTune' => $iTune));

    $json = json_encode($gamePlatform);
    $a = str_replace('\/', '/', $json);
    echo $a;
```

Comment: It was coming ok ..but when I am encoding it through json encode then becomes llike that